# Textmate - open new windows in the same location as the old one.

Tags: interface, textmate

This might sound like a strange question, but does anybody know how to force Textmate to define the location on screen where Textmate opens new window.

I want new window to be opened on top of previous one and with the same size - I find it better for navigation/browsing/switching between windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question [has already been (partly) answered](https://superuser.com/questions/233943/default-position-and-size-for-new-textmate-windows).

In the past I used a collection of Applescripts to manipulate the size and position of windows, now I use [a fork of ShiftIt](https://github.com/fikovnik/ShiftIt). It's free and does everything I need.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find that for some reason.